# Get List of MethodHandle from key fields which are private in an object

Tags: java, private-members, collectors, methodhandle

I have a list of object with many private fields and I would want to group them according to a few key fields that come from a database. The method class is in another package.
My object would look like

```
public class MyObject {
private String field1;

private String field2;

private String field3;

private Integer field4;
...}
```

and the key fields could be any combination of the fields in the Object

I have tried to get a list of MethodHandle for key fields. This list of MethodHandle would be later streamed and invoked for Collectors.groupingBy to form a Map.

```
private static Map<List<String>, List<MyObject>>
        groupListBy(List<MyObject> objList, String[] keyFields) {

    final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    List<MethodHandle> handles = Arrays.stream(keyFields)
            .map(field -> {
                try {
                    // What I tried by didn't work
                    // Field f = objList.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
                    // f.setAccessible(true);
                    return lookup.findGetter(MyObject.class, field, String.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
     .
     .
};
```

However, there would be an Illegal Access Exception for accessing a private member when forming a list of MethodHandle for the private fields in the MyObject.

May I know how can I access those fields.
Thank you!

Edit: I know there is a method called privateLookupIn() in Java 9, but I'm using Java 8 currently.

Comment: Since this is about accessibility, you should mention in which classes/package the particular code is located. Apparently, the `groupListBy` method is not in your `Object` class, but don’t let us guess. And well, don’t name your class `Object` if you don’t want to get into trouble.

Comment: @Holger thank you, I have corrected them

Comment: Ok. Which class is calling `groupListBy`? Is there a possibility to let `MyObject` provide the necessary lookup object? That would be the simplest solution, not needing access override (besides the Java 9 solution).

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some other answers and came up with this

```
    final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    Object obj = new Object();
    List<MethodHandle> handles = Arrays.stream(keyFields)
            .map(field -> {
                try {
                    PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(field, Object.class);
                    Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
                    getter.setAccessible(true);
                    MethodHandle pmh = lookup.unreflect(getter);
                    return pmh;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that the “getter” you’ve got with this method is a `public … get…()` method, which does not need access override, unlike the “getter” returned by `MethodHandles.Lookup.findGetter` which is a handle to access the `private` field.